# How to display the key of key array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

This is the content of $records
[image]

If I wanted to display the "key" of this key array, how to code?

e.g. in first round of foreach loop I like to display
1 (key), 1 (id), 10 (price) and so on.
I would use $record['id'], $record['price'], but I don't know what to code to display the key?

Comment: You can use the "array_keys" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($records as $key=>$record){
  echo "key: ".$key."</br>";
  echo "ID: ".$record['id']."</br>";
  echo "Price: ".$record['price']."</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($records as $key => $record) {
    echo $key;
}
```

Check foreach in PHP manual for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($records as $key=>$val){
   echo $key;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($records as $key => $record) {
  echo $key . '(key), ' . $record['id'] . '(id), ' . $record['price'] . '(price)';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use a foreach ?

```
foreach($records as $key => $value) {
     echo "Current key: ".$key."<br />";
     print_r($value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
foreach ($records as $record) {
    foreach ($record as $key => $value) {
        echo $value . '(' . $key . ')';
    }
}
?>
```